# Static pattern to retain objects through configuration changes

Tags: java, android, static, instance

*I am experienced enough to know about configuration changes. I know how to save and restore the instance state of a `View`, `Activity`, `Fragment` or whatever, and I know that we should rely on that, rather than simply make objects static.*

This question is about `static`ness of a field. In "pure Java" declaring an object as `static` serves the purpose of having it shared among instances.
In the android system, declaring a `static` field is also a quick way to have it *survive* configuration changes, when our instance is recreated and its fields are cleared.

Example:

```
public class FooFragment extends Fragment {

    private static Object sObject;

    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            sObject = new Object();
            sObject.toString();
        } else {
            sObject.toString();
        }
    }

}
```

In this case, `sObject` can be initialized when the fragment is **created**, and just fetched when the fragment is **recreated**. Issues arise when our class is not static itself, is designed as a base class, or is an `abstract` class.

```
public abstract class BaseFragment extends Fragment {

    protected static Object sObject;
}

public class FooFragment extends BaseFragment {

    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            sObject = new Object();
            sObject.toString();
        } else {
            sObject.toString();
        }
    }
}

public class BarFragment extends BaseFragment {

    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            sObject = new Object();
            sObject.toString();
        } else {
            sObject.toString();
        }
    }
}
```

Now both `FooFragment`  and `BarFragment` will access (and impredictably use) the same instance of `sObject`. That is the point of staticness, but is not what we want. We want `FooFragment` and `BarFragment` to have **their own sObject**; we just want it to survive configuration changes and platform-driven recreation.

## Question

How can I design the base class for this goal?

This is what I came up with, but I’m sure there’s something better.

```
public abstract class BaseFragment extends Fragment {

    private static HashMap<String, Object> sObjects;

    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            Object o = new Object();
            sObjects.put(getClass().getName(), o);
        }
    }

    protected final Object getObject() {
        return sObjects.get(getClass().getName());
    }
}
```

Basically I keep a static map, indexing by child class name.

Comment: "declaring a static field is also a quick way to have it survive configuration changes" -- if you have to ask a Stack Overflow question about the technique, it is no longer "a quick way", IMHO. Your approach risks memory leaks, and it is unclear what you are gaining compared to using a retained fragment (or the saved instance state `Bundle`, for things that can go in there).

Comment: @CommonsWare well I have posted my solution, I’d like to know if there is anything better from a design point of view. My object can’t be bundled, and setRetainInstance() is a (in my opinion and in my case) bad solution for BaseFragments, but is not a solution for BaseViews.

Comment: I think I spend some 60% of my developing time configuring state restorations in the “platform” way, so I know what I’m talking about. I’d like to use this static strategy for a specific object that can’t be treated in standard ways.

Comment: "so I know what I’m talking about" -- you might. Lots of other people encountering this question might not, which is why context matters for them, even if it does not matter to you.

Comment: @CommonsWare so what can I add to the question? This looks bad to my eyes as to yours. Are you concerned that other people might see this as a platform way to retain stuff?

Comment: "so what can I add to the question?" -- probably nothing at this point that has not been covered in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you are implementing a global cache. The fact that you happen to be using it for configuration changes is just a detail. Hence, you need to consider the standard stuff for global caches. For example, consider `HashMap<String, WeakReference<Object>>`, so if you fail to remove the object from the `HashMap` due to a coding bug or unhandled exception, the long-term impact will be modest.

In terms of more Android-specific considerations, nothing that goes into that cache should be configuration-dependent, such as the value of a string culled from string resources. These need to be rebuilt, as the configuration change may affect their value.

Also, nothing that goes into that cache should be dependent upon the pre-configuration-change environment, such as views owned by the former activity, to help reduce memory leaks.

While you think that retained fragments are inappropriate, you might consider looking at their implementation, or the implementation of other global caches (e.g., Picasso's image cache), for other ideas of what might befall you.

Answer (score 0):

Your method will work if you have a small app. However there are a couple of things that this can make difficult.

**1. Memory footprint:** Every static instance is retained even if you are not using that screen. As stated above, this is not a big deal if your application is small, but can cause issues if your application grows.

**2. Testability:** Testing static things is not fun :(

There may be easier ways to achieve your goals.

**Option A** Load from DB. Basically save as little state as possible (maybe ID of data your are looking at) and load data on orientation change.

**Option B** Make saving state easier with a library such as [IcePick](https://github.com/frankiesardo/icepick) You can save primitives, or create customer converters for objects (e.g. Use GSON to convert object to JSON).